# Azure Blob List Paging

Tags: azure, paging, azure-blob-storage

I have in my container 3000 files.In my gridview I am show the list of container blobs but 3000 is too much and is not good for performance (my thought :) ).

I need a paging code , example my grid pagesize is 50 I will show the first 50 blob in my container for my first page in gridview.Of course I need in pageindexchanging more code :)

Or does it not affect performance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use azure storage SDK's [ListBlobsSegmented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434672.aspx) method to achieve your requirement.

The ListBlobsSegmented inclue maxResults parameter.

maxResults:
A non-negative integer value that indicates the maximum number of results to be returned at a time, up to the per-operation limit of 5000. If this value is null, the maximum possible number of results will be returned, up to 5000.

So you could just search 50 records when your page is load firstly.

When your page index changed, you could call the search method to search the right number of blobs according to gridview index.

Notice:To include the performance, we will not get all the blobs at once to know how many blobs in your container. So we couldn't know the total number of blobs.I suggest you could search 100 blobs at first time, if the customer click the page 2, it will search next 100 blobs.

Here is a example demo, hope it gives you some tips:
Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="50"  OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" runat="server">
 </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
  BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //1*100 is the numebr of blobs you will list
                ListBlobResult(1*100);
            }
        }

        public void ListBlobResult(int index)
        {
           CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connectionstring");
           var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
           var container = client.GetContainerReference("foo2");
            string prefix = null;
            bool useFlatBlobListing = true;
            BlobListingDetails blobListingDetails = BlobListingDetails.All;
           // int maxBlobsPerRequest = 50;
            List<IListBlobItem> blobs = new List<IListBlobItem>();

            if (index <= 5000)
            {
                var listingResult = container.ListBlobsSegmented(prefix, useFlatBlobListing, blobListingDetails, index, continuationToken, null, null);
                continuationToken = listingResult.ContinuationToken;
                blobs.AddRange(listingResult.Results);
            }
            else
            {
                do
                {
                    var listingResult = container.ListBlobsSegmented(prefix, useFlatBlobListing, blobListingDetails, index, continuationToken, null, null);
                    continuationToken = listingResult.ContinuationToken;
                    blobs.AddRange(listingResult.Results);
                    index = index - 5000;
                }
                while (continuationToken != null);
            }
            DataTable d1 = new DataTable();
            d1.Columns.Add("Id");
            d1.Columns.Add("Url");
            foreach (var item in blobs)
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
                {
                    CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
                    d1.Rows.Add(blob.Name, blob.Uri);
                }
            }

            GridView1.DataSource = d1;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }


        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {

            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            //(e.NewPageIndex*100)+100 is the numebr of blobs you will list
            ListBlobResult((e.NewPageIndex*100)+100);    
        }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Do you know, you are the king :) Thank you so much it's working :)

Comment: When you have time can you help about getting container ListBlobsSegmented with SasUri.I am getting the list there is no problem but when the user refresh the page or comes 5min later another one.I am always get the uri links with SaS is it bad for performance .? I have viewstates for container bloblist but I have 1000 user :)

Comment: You want to use SAS to list blob?  Could you please explain more about "When the user refresh the page or comes 5min later another one" ? I suggest you could start a new thread and post more details information, it will be more easily for us to find the solution.

Comment: Sorry for writing late , I read today a blog and they wrote , when you create example for a user container sas uri for uploading you dont need to create another container sas uri for another user (without expiry).I thought you will create always for everyone a new container sas uri.Is it right ? one piece is enough for all ?

Comment: The SAS is generic, anyone who have the right blob url and SAS token could access the blob without any authorization.

Comment: I want the same pagination for table how can i implement that

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for pagination sample in JAVA and for some reason google gives this question as top 3. Anyway I found a solution and if anybody interested how to do pagination using java and the latest MS azure client here you go.

```
void listAllForContainer(BlobContainerClient container) {
    String token = null;
    do {
        PagedResponse<BlobItem> pr = container
                .listBlobs(options, token, Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                .iterableByPage()
                .iterator()
                .next();

        token = pr.getContinuationToken();
        List<BlobItem> pageItems = pr.getValue();
        pageItems.forEach(i->System.out.println(i.getName()));

    } while (token != null);
}
```

Azure artifact

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
        <version>12.X.X</version>
    </dependency>
```