# BlobContainerClient - Azure Storage - Java SDK (12.14.2) - method listBlobs maxResults and pagination

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-blob-storage

Iterating over available blobs in the Azure storage via Java SDK (azure-spring-boot-starter-storage) doesn't work with the maxresults query param.

```
ListBlobsOptions listBlobsOptions= new ListBlobsOptions()
    .setDetails(new BlobListDetails()
        .setRetrieveDeletedBlobs(false)
        .setRetrieveSnapshots(false))
    .setMaxResultsPerPage(pageSize);

blobContainerClient.listBlobs(listBlobsOptions, continuationToken, Duration.ofSeconds(3));
```

The listBlobs methods works and return all the available **BlobItems as PagedIterable**. Ideally, it should stop with the marker taking the maxresults query param passed in the request via setMaxResultsPerPage method.

Automatically a marker has been generated and a new request has been sent by SDK to fetch the next results. Finally, all the blobs available have been returned from Azure storage instead of paged blobs list.

*E.g. request autocreated by SDK  GET{uri=/containername?restype=container&comp=list&marker=...&maxresults=1*

How pagination will work using the Synchronous **BlobServiceClient**?

Answer (score 0):

On workaround try with following solutions

**Solution 1):**
Try with using the [**Listblobssegmented()**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobdirectory.listblobssegmented?view=azure-java-legacy#com_microsoft_azure_storage_blob_CloudBlobDirectory_listBlobsSegmented__) method .

the `ListBlobsSegmented` include the  `maxResults` parameter.

**maxResults**: A non-negative integer value that indicates the maximum number of results to be returned at a time, up to the per-operation limit of 5000. If this value is null, the maximum possible number of results will be returned, up to 5000.

**Note: If more blobs are available, then you’ll get a continuation token which you can use to fetch next set of blobs. This continuation token can be found in element in response body.**

**Solution 2:** try with this code pagination using java and the latest MS azure

```
Void listAllForContainer(BlobContainerClient container) {
    String token = null;
    do {
        PagedResponse<BlobItem> pr = container
                .listBlobs(options, token, Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                .iterableByPage()
                .iterator()
                .next();

        token = pr.getContinuationToken();
        List<BlobItem> pageItems = pr.getValue();
        pageItems.forEach(i->System.out.println(i.getName()));

    } while (token != null);
}
```

For more details refer this **[SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565661/azure-blob-list-paging)**:

Comment: Even if you see the original request is same as Solution#1 which includes maxresults @QueryParam in each request sent to MS. The response from MS is also paged but the actual problem is sequential request has been sent via SDK whereas it should have stopped

Comment: Solution#2 seems reasonable to me but in the first place it gives a post-processing view, which does mean once a complete response has been collected by listBlobs then you iterate on the pages